# How to change background of one cell in QTableWidget in PyQt?

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I need to change the background of cell (1, 1) or any cell (m, n) of QTableWidget in runtime but background of other cells is defined with `app.setStyleSheet(STYLE_SHEET)`. Any methods are welcome:
editing the STYLE_SHEET itself (so that the rest of the cells do not change), adding code, switching to PyQt 6, ...).

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
class Table(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        # Creating table
        table = QtWidgets.QTableWidget()
        table.setRowCount(4)
        table.setColumnCount(2)
        table.setAlternatingRowColors(True)
        table.setItem(0, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem("00"))
        table.setItem(0, 1, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem("01"))
        table.setItem(1, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem("10"))
        table.setItem(1, 1, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem("11"))
        self.setCentralWidget(table)
        self.show()
        

        # set color for item (1, 1)
        item = table.item(1, 1)
        item.setBackground(QtGui.QColor(255, 0, 0)) # doesn't work
        item.setData(QtCore.Qt.BackgroundRole, QtGui.QColor(255, 0, 0)) # doesn't work



STYLE_SHEET = '''
        QTableWidget::item {
            color: red;
            background-color: #DFD0CA;
            }
        QTableWidget::item:alternate {
            color: red;
            background-color: #DFE0CA;
            }
        QTableWidget::item:selected {
            selection-color: blue;
            background-color: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0.5, y2: 0.5, stop: 0 #FF92BB, stop: 1 white);
            }
'''

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    app.setStyleSheet(STYLE_SHEET)
    ex = Table()
    app.exec()
```

Lines `item.setBackground` and `item.setData` work only when `app.setStyleSheet(STYLE_SHEET)` is disabled.
QTableWidgetItem doesn't have own `setStyleSheet` or `setObjectName` method.

Comment: Setting stylesheets that specify the colors of the `::item` pseudo element will always result in completely override existing background/foreground roles of the item model. If you want to use stylesheets and also respect those roles, you must use a custom delegate.